# moving mails in gmail by using google api is not working in corporate company

Tags: c

Moving mails one label to another label in gmail by using google api is not working corporate company, but is perfectly working out side of company  network.please any one suggest me.why it is not working in corporate company network.

Comment: Because they block the port?

Comment: reading mails from gmail and sending mails to gmail by using google api is working perfectly in corporate company..why moving mails in gmail  is not working  in corporate company

Comment: @Aganju  :   reading mails from gmail and sending mails to gmail by using google api is working perfectly in corporate company..why moving mails in gmail is not working in corporate company –

Comment: @Aganju:  port  number is not blocked.please suggest me

Comment: I am not qualified to give you any suggestions, sorry. I only had the idea with the port in passing.

Comment: any one help me